# Where did my battery status go?

Tags: battery

I am a relatively new ubuntu user, so this might be a problem with an easy fix, but my battery gauge recently disappeared, and it treats my laptop as a desktop computer even though I know it registers that its a laptop. I have traced the problem to this URL:
http://ppa.launchpad.net/iaz/battery-status/ubuntu
and when I run the sudo apt update or sudo apt-get update command, this url gives back a 404 not found error. I even reinstalled ubuntu, but it did not fix the problem... Has anyone else had this issue/do you know how to fix it. I have unsucessfully searching for other people with this problem, but I cant find anything.. plz help :(

Comment: forgot to mention, the computer I am using is a 2009 MacBook Pro

Comment: What is your current Ubuntu version? What is your desktop environment? Please note that mentioned PPA does not have updates after [2011 year](http://ppa.launchpad.net/iaz/battery-status/ubuntu/dists/) or [2012 year](https://launchpad.net/~iaz/+archive/ubuntu/battery-status-devel). Are you sure that battery indication will not work without PPA?

Comment: Edit your question with the full unredacted output of `sudo apt update`.  Please make sure that you use the editing tools to properly format this output as `code` so that we can actually read it.  Alternatively, you can use [markdown](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

I use Xubuntu thus my GUI is XFCE.  There is a power management plug in, be sure it is an 'item' on a panel (probably panel 0)